# Monotouch SplitView Example Cant Change ViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to learn how to use the UISplitViewController and I am using the "SplitView" example available from Monotouch. I understand how it works and communicates between the Master and Detail controllers.

Therefore it can't be hard to change the detail controller? So I have made a very small amendment and it doesn't work! I have read you must use the SetViewControllers but this doesn't exist in the Monotouch stack.  Where am I going wrong?

It's exactly the same code as the example from Montouch except for the lines below:

```
public class MainSplitView : UISplitViewController
{       
    protected Screens.MasterView.MasterTableView masterView;
    protected Screens.DetailView.DetailViewScreen detailView;
    protected TestViewController testViewController; // *** Added this line

    public MainSplitView () : base()
    {
        // create our master and detail views
        masterView = new Screens.MasterView.MasterTableView ();
        detailView = new Screens.DetailView.DetailViewScreen ();

        masterView.RowClicked += (object sender, MasterView.MasterTableView.RowClickedEventArgs e) => 
        {
            detailView.Text = e.Item;

            testViewController = new TestViewController();  // *** Added this line
            ViewControllers[0] = masterView;         // *** Added this line
            ViewControllers[1] = testViewController; // *** Added this line
          // the UISplitViewController.SetViewControllers does not exist! ???
        };

         ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { masterView, detailView };

     }
```

All help greatly appreciated!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ViewControllers` exactly how do you do are doing it in the other place:

```
ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { masterView, detailView };
```

Just do this:

```
ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { masterView, testViewController };
```

Comment: Worked great! So obvious couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks.